# Hive query hangs in 0.13

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have 12GB of table data.

My table looks like this:

```
userid name score
1      abc   1
1      pqr   1
2      mno   1
2      pqr   1
.
.
.
750000 mno   1
```

and this is my query:

```
select a.userid as user1,b.userid as user2, sum(a.score*b.score) as score,count(distinct a.name) as distinct_name from table a join table b on(a.name=b.name) limit 10;
```

It runs for hours but no result is returned. How can I fix this?

Comment: you have 2 tables with same column name??????

Comment: No, I have only one table and i m doing self join on it.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
select a.userid as user1,b.userid as user2, sum(a.score*b.score) as score,count(distinct a.name) as distinct_name 
from table a join table b on(a.name=b.name)
group by a.userid , b.userid
limit 10;
```

put your table name in place of table;

Comment: take the sample data of 100 rows and check with above query, running or not?

Comment: ya its running but when run same query on 7,50,000 user it hangs up